# Detail section of an MS Access form needs to allow access to all table records one at a time

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a MS Access form with a subform on it. Opened on its own, the subform can run a "Find Record" action to pull any record from the single table that supplies data to it. As a child placed in the detail section of another form, however, it looks like the subform is "bound" to a single record that is selected on another control in the detail section (the other control is located outside the subform). Is there any way to "detach" the subform's dependency on the record that is current for the detail section, and allow the subform to select from a full set of records?

Comment: Check the Link Master and Child properties of the subform control.

Comment: I'm checking on this. Many thanks.

Comment: Note that if you remove that link it will no longer be a "subform" it because it will have no relationship at all to the selected parent record.